# Variable created from another variable in AMPL

Tags: ampl

In AMPL I have a set of variables x[e], for some calculations I need a binary variable w[e] which equals 1 when x[e] > 0 and 0 if x[e] = 0. I tried a lot of stuff to make this constraint, but I failed to come up with something. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your problem the following way:

```
var u  binary;
```

this is our binary variable that will be 0 or 1.
Then we put following constraint:

```
subject to U_constraint :
    x <= 999999 * u;
```

Now when x = 0 then AMPL will make u = 0 and when x != 0 obviously u = 1.

Comment: What prevents u from being 1 when x = 0?

Comment: Truth to be told I haven't been using AMPL since 2013 so I don't really recall this method by I have used that in my university project and it was working. If you find any mistakes please share and I will correct this answer for the others.